# How to manage sso cookie

Tags: java, cookies, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I have 2 websites , SiteA,SiteB and AuthSite , I am following OAUTH2, I like to have a SSO between my two sites. I am using java and backend.

whenever user clicks login button on both Sites (A,B) I will redirect to AuthSite and check for any cookie saved on this already . if saved I will redirect to the OAUTH2's redirect URL with #access_token=newtoken. if not I will land on login page.

In this case the Cookie will be created only once , means cookie created only for AuthSite.

the cookie will be like this -> sampleCookie=accesstoken

user logged in at SiteA and He try to move to SiteB, That time what are the things I need to take care ?

like ,

1. Whether I replace the existing cookie with new Access_token value ?
2. If that is the case what about the SiteA cookie?
3. Or I have maintain both the values . like sampleCookie=["accesstoken1","accesstoken2"]?
4. Both site needs to have different expire time or same for all?

I didnt find any document for this . any one have idea on this?

Comment: A very good discussion is here:  http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/ ... It's not Java-specific, and it does specifically discuss how to handle multiple domains.

Comment: @MikeRobinson, thank you very much, it helps me a lot.